# Automated builds of BizTalk 2009 projects using Team System 2008 Build

Tags: tfs, biztalk, build-automation, biztalk-2009

I'm trying to configure automated build of BizTalk 2009 projects using Team Foundation Server 2008.

We have a staging server which has BizTalk 2009 installed. I ran the Team Foundation Server Build Setup on this server, and it can build non-BizTalk projects OK. However, BizTalk projects fail to build. I suspected something was amiss when "Deployment" was not a valid build type! I tried copying various things over from a developer PC which has BizTalk and Visual Studio 2008 installed, but still couldn't get it to work.

I don't really want to install Visual Studio on the staging server, but without it the "Developer Tools and SDK" option in the BizTalk install is greyed out. I guess I need this in order for BizTalk projects to compile.

So, my question is can a BizTalk 2009 server be used as a TFS build agent to build BizTalk projects without having Visual Studio installed. If the answer is no, what's the smallest part of VS that can be installed to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

[Randal van Splunteren answered](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkgeneral/thread/376ade6f-9010-4b7c-a9f6-7406c07ed4e7/#289651bb-15bb-4b2a-b84b-58074e134552) on MSDN:

> There is a BizTalk installable feature called 'Project Build Component' (under 'Additional Software'). You can select/unselect it during installation of BizTalk. . . . It allows for builds without Visual Studio.
>
> Be aware that you can only build stuff. For generating MSI packages you will need a BizTalk server (remote or on the build server itself).